# Perl args and defining it

Tags: perl, args, hashref

Hello I am trying to understand Perl better. I come from Ruby and trying to wrap my head around Perl for fun. Let's say I have this code block here.

```
$self->doSomething(
    {   record     => $record,
        listing    => [ $foo, $bar, $baz ],
        passedargs => { something => $val, another => $val2 },
    }
);
```

What exactly is defined as `$args`? My thought process from reading Perl docs is something like `my ($self, $args) = @_;` Meaning everything within the `doSomething` block is considered `$args` and if I wanted to access it. I would `my $args = @_[0];`

Just curious if I am thinking about this correctly? if not care to explain?

Comment: Since `$self->doSomething` is method call, first argument to method (`$_[0]`) is always object itself, and rest of them are parameters (`$_[1], etc.`). In this case `$arg` is hash reference from `$_[1]`.

Comment: "In this case $arg is hash reference from $_[1]" So this means $arg is a hash reference of the values record, listing and passedargs? being the keys?

Comment: First you assign input parameters `my ($self, $args) = @_;` and then `$args->{record}` to access value of `$record` (`$_[1]{record}` would be the same thing but much less readable).

Comment: Thank you, this is starting to clear up things for me. I really appreciate it. So just one more example if I wanted to just access bar inside of listings. I would $args->{listing}[1]?

Comment: Yes, correct. btw, if coming from Ruby you might be interested in [perl5i module](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/perl5i-v2.13.0/lib/perl5ifaq.pod)

Comment: Thank You. I will go ahead and check that out.

Comment: If you want to do a little less typing you can do `$self->doSomething(record => $record, listing => [$foo, $bar, $baz]);`
Then, in doSomething, have `my ($self, %args) = @_; $args{record};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are invoking `doSomething` as a method call, the first argument will be the object you are calling the method on (i.e. that which is on the left hand side of the arrow operator: `$self`).

The second argument will be the hashref you are passing between the `(` and the `)`.

You access a particular member of the hashref just as you would for any other hashref.

```
sub doSomething {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;
    my $record = $args->{record};
```